# SVNでチェックアウト時にエラー ra_serf:The server sent a truncated HTTP response body

Tags: svn

SVNで他人のファイルを受け取るためにチェックアウトをしたいのですが、以下のエラー文が出てしまいます。

```
ra_serf:The server sent a truncated HTTP response body.
```

調べてみるとこのエラーが出る方は多いようで、それらを見ながら解消するために行ったことは以下の通りです。

- クリーンアップを行う(複数回)
- 上の階層からチェックアウトしてみる
- 止まったファイルの直前の階層からチェックアウトしてみる
- タイムアウト値を増やす
- 設定ファイルでHTTP圧縮を無効にする
- Apache2.4以降にする

しかし、エラー文は変わらず一向にチェックアウトができません。
ちなみに該当のファイルをコミットしてくれた方以外のファイルは全てチェックアウトできます。
コミットの仕方に問題があるのでしょうか。
解決方法をご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたらご教授お願いいたします。